Splitting upon insertion in hierarchical clustering
It's my understanding that, upon the insertion of a new element, complete-link hierarchical clustering can lead the splitting of a cluster so as to maintain its "spherical compactness". Do splitting upon insertion also happen for single- or average-link clustering? I can't think of any simple examples.
